# Dendrogram with overlapping branches produced in R (comparative phylogenetic analysis)

Tags: r

I am looking to create a fan dendrogram with a heat map of a continuous variable for 120 species of birds. The current code I'm running creates an extremely messy figure where multiple branches overlap.

[Example of dendrogram produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0euQ3.png)

This same problem does not occur when creating a normal dendrogram.
I obtained the phylogenetic trees from vertlife.org. The raw data is composed of 1000 randomly generated Erikson trees condensed into a consensus tree with `consensus.edges` in `phytools` where non-negative least squares edge lengths were computed using the mean patristic distance matrix. This tree is not rooted.
Unfortunately I do not know how to create a representative data sample of my phylogenetic tree. I've tried a couple times but the resulting dataset does not create the same problem. Note this dataset did not involve forming a consensus tree.

```
#libraries
library(ape)
library(maps)
library(phytools)

#download phylogenetic trees
tree<-read.nexus(file.choose())

#form consensus tree
tree<-consensus.edges(tree,method="least.squares")

#check consensus tree
tree
# Phylogenetic tree with 120 tips and 112 internal nodes.
# Tip labels:
#   Chauna_torquata, Cygnus_melancoryphus, Cygnus_atratus, Cygnus_olor, 
# Anser_indicus, Branta_ruficollis, ...
# Node labels:
#   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
# Unrooted; includes branch lengths.

#upload biological variable
data<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE,row.names=1)
data<-as.matrix(data)[,1]

#check data
data

#create dendrogram in pdf form
pdf(file="birdMap.pdf",width=20,height=20)
obj<-contMap(tree,data,fsize=c(0.6,1),lwd=3,outline=FALSE)
dev.off()
```

Comment: If you're struggling to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), perhaps add a .csv of your data to Google Drive (or similar) and provide a link (if your data aren't confidential)? As you state, your sample data do not reproduce the issue so a full dataset is most likely needed.